# Cannot read property 'ajaxSetup' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax

Then i trying to make new project console shows a problem Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajaxSetup' of undefined at csrf_jquery_ajax_setup

code is here

```
var csrfData = <?php echo json_encode(get_csrf_for_ajax()); ?>;

        if (typeof(jQuery) == 'undefined') {
            window.deferAfterjQueryLoaded.push(function () {
                csrf_jquery_ajax_setup();
            });
            window.addEventListener('load',function(){
                csrf_jquery_ajax_setup();
            }, true);
        } else {
            csrf_jquery_ajax_setup();
        }
    function csrf_jquery_ajax_setup() {
       $.ajaxSetup({
        data: csrfData.formatted
    });
```

Comment: Then `$` is `undefined`.  Where do you load jQuery?  Where do you call this function?

Comment: i added all code to example

Comment: and console shows problem at $.ajaxSetup({